# Getting data from gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to use a gridview in asp.net and when I click the button all rows in gridview will save in the array and I can use them one by one.

Please tell me the solution or suggest me a book or link or ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I suppose your button is not in the grid. On click event of the button you can write following code

```
string[] str = new string[gv.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            str[i]= gv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
        }
```

And you can have all values of Gridview cell against each row.

Now it's up to you how you will use this array further.

Thanks